# Book about a man who finds a way to another dimension with lizard people

Tags: story-identification, books

What is the name of the book about a dude who found a hidden portal in his house to a lizard's world where humans are like sheep?

Comment: Yo dude, I'm going to need you to take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and add in a hell of a lot more details, because right now, no ones ever going to identify that book.

Answer (score 6):

## *Red Flame Burning* (1985), by Ward Hawkins?

[image: Book cover depicting a man, a lizard people and some kind of a pet beetle]

> Harry Borg is an aging alcoholic who is waiting for death when one day a nail appears in the middle of his apartment sticking out of an invisible wall. When the hole caused by the nail is enlarged (from the other side)a nice guy named Guss pops in. Guss is a reptilian humanoid who seems to find Harry VERY interesting. One day Harry wakes up to find he is now young, handsome and about to go on an adventure that is out of this world. It seems Guss's people need help. While they are very advanced they have been fighting a war for thousands of years and are starting to lose it. They figure the aggressive human's courage and strengths can help them win it. But what happens when the Hero finds out that some of his 'Allies' look at him like we would look at a good T-bone steak? Lizard-people with flying cars, giant bugs used as guard dogs and Grade "A" humans that go great with barbecue sauce, what more could you ask for in a sci-fi book?
> <sub>-[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345321219)</sub>

Found by Googling `portal lizard world`, and then finding a link to [Sci-fi series about a parallel world peopled by lizard men, the portal of which was discovered by an alcoholic in his apartment?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50203/33591).